# Is there a way to find a value pair in O(n + klog(n) + k^2) time in python?

Tags: python, time

Assume there is an array A. For example A = [0, 2, 5, 4]. And we have a number k that is the sum of two elements in array A. For example k = 6 = 2 + 4. How can we solve this problem in O(n + klog(n) + k^2) time. I know that there is a faster way using pointers but for this problem it is needed to do it in this specific time.

```
def find_pair_with_sum(A, k):
    n = len(A)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i + 1, n):
            if A[i] + A[j] == k:
                return A[i], A[j]
    return 'No Pair'

A = [3, 5, 2, 7, 4, 9]
k = 10
pair = find_pair_with_sum(A, k)
```

This code has a time complexity of O(n^2) which is too fast.
Thank you in advance for your help!